# Text component with comment boxes

Tags: java, swing, text

I am looking for a swing component which is capable to show plain text with comment boxes. Recently I developed one using JEditorPane as a base class https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8155778/comment_boxes.png. Though I am not very happy with performance (mostly because of a lot painting), etc. 
 Could you point me to any components, tutorials, etc?
Thank you in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

There is not such component for Swing as i know (even in large extension libraries like Jide), but i bet your paintings speed could be optimized to achieve required performance.  If you post your painting code i might be able to help with that...

Comment: Thank you for your response and offer! I am thinking to wrap my component into an open source project involving more people into development...

Comment: @AlexanderTkachuk That is a good idea, but you will need a good documentation and site/storage for your project if you really want to attract any developers